# Roblox how to change object name in game

Tags: roblox

Hi I need to make an object name change after 300 second Please reply to my question soon. Seen all tutorial but it not understandable please I hope someone replies to me soon

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script for that object and write into the script:

```
wait(300)
script.Parent.Name = "My New Name"
```

Comment: I need to repeat it self like e.g I need to name an object "key" after 300 seconds it could change its name to e.g "door" after 300s it should repeat it all over again

Comment: I made this script but dont know if it is right or wronglocal key = 1
local key = 1
while key < 5 do
    script.Parent.Name = "key 1"
    wait(300)
    script.Parent.Name = "Key 1"
end

Comment: Do you mean that some other script renames it to some thing and this script is supposed to rename it back every 300s? Btw, I would generally advise against using object names as variables. Instead, Roblox has the concept of value objects, such as "BoolValue" or "StringValue" that you can create in your object tree - https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StringValue